# Как подключиться к базе Mysql из java программы (Java 1.8), используя ODBC?

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc, odbc

**Есть рабочий код.**

Он работает если использовать при сборке более взрослые версии JDK(до 1.8).

Хочу разобраться, можно ли использовать JDBC-ODBC подключение совместно с java 1.8?

Как сделать так, чтобы этот код таки скомпилировался и заработал под java 1.8:

```
package com.airbase.db;

import java.sql.*;

public class MysqlODBC {    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Connection con;
            Statement stmt;
            ResultSet rs;
            try{
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:air_base","root","root");

                stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM plain");  

                while(rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("ID") + " " + rs.getString("number"));
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Мне необходимо выполнить подключение с базой **Mysql** используя **ODBC**...

В java 1.8 JDBC-ODBC драйвер выпилили из JDK поэтому этот код выдает ошибку:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

**Есть ли способ  подключиться к базе Mysql из  java программы (Java 1.8) используя JDBC-ODBC драйвер?**

// То что лучше использовать JDBC я знаю... но хочу разобраться с подключением именно так как я написал... и именно под java 1.8

Comment: "import" пробовали ?

Comment: @barmaglott в этой ситуации import никак не поможет... не понятно откуда импортировать... ведь из Oracle jdk 1.8   убрали .JDBC-ODBC драйвер. И соответственно и необходимые  классы будут не найдены..

Comment: Вы драйвер скачали?

Comment: @barmaglott, скачал [ODBC Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) и  настроил....

Comment: помог "import"?